# What does the "bad URI(absolute but no path): http://" error in ruby on rails mean and how do I prevent it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

**I'm getting the error below:**

```
bad URI(absolute but no path): http://
```

**From view:**

```
= get_video(micropost.link) if micropost.link
```

**Helper method:**

```
 def get_video(url)
    OpenGraph.fetch(url)
 end
```

How ever if I manually place the exact same URL/Link (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OLz4sr971w) from the db in place of "micropost.link" in my view there is no error.

I have no idea what the issue could be and how the string stored in my db is any different from the copy and pasted string but I'm sure the issue is very simple so I'm looking forward to a solution thanks.

Kind regards

Comment: Could you please post here that `url`, which `microspot.link` returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed my issue. I overlooked the fact that there were rows in my db where video links weren't present so rather than checking if a link existed I should have checked for blanks.

```
= get_video(micropost.link) unless micropost.link.blank?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OpenGraph.fetch(url) 
  calls -> RestClient.get(uri).body
```

RestClient in turn expects a full uri including the protocol e.g. http:// so you need to ensure you are passing a url not just an absolute path.

Comment: The URL stored in the db is http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OLz4sr971w do not sure why it's not working .